# What are the Azure DocumentDB limitations?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We want to use Azure DocumentDB but before that would like to know if there are any limitations, drawbacks, disadvantages and advantages?

Comment: I removed subjective stuff to give this question a chance of not being closed.

Comment: It is still very broad and open ended question.

Comment: @usr - the issue is that the question asks about advantages / disadvantages. This is wide open for interpretation. As far as limitations go, these are [clearly documented](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-limits/) on azure.com, under documentation->documentdb. And these limits are evolving, especially since the service is still considered Preview.

Comment: I guess this question is unsalvageable.

Comment: I find the uservoice/feedback list for DocumentDB quite handy to spot any major "painpoints" https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/filters/top

Answer (score 5):

The following post describes the limits and quota enforcements of DocumentDB.
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-limits/

Comment: That link is now just a redirection to: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/documentdb/